# Identifying an isomorphism

Tags: group-isomorphism

Let G be a group of order 7 and θ(x)=x^4 then θ is?
 - not one one
 - not onto
 - not an homomorphism
 - one one onto and homomorphism
Clearly x^4 is not one one and onto but the correct answer is fourth one.

Comment: Why do you think it's not one-to-one or onto?

Comment: Why do you write, "clearly $x^4$ is not one one..." Do you understand how things work in a group of order 7?

Comment: As a normal function it's not one one...I'm not very sure how things work out in groups.

Comment: All right I get it.... For every element in the group it gives distinct images so it's one one..